# Best way to cache Ubuntu updates and control when new updates retrieved

Tags: apt-cache, apt-cacher-ng

What is the best way to cache Ubuntu updates on a server and prevent new updates being added to the cache (from the internet) until I am ready to update the cache?

I have read about apt-cacher, apt-cacher-ng, and squid-deb-proxy but in my case

a) the clients needing updates will not have internet access, only access to internal servers. (any conditions where above solutions fail in that case? ).

b) I need to provide the exact same update to multiple clients so need to prevent the cache from being updated between updates to different clients. (Need to turn updating of cache itself on and off. )

Can any of the above solutions work in that manner?

Answer (score 0):

apt-cacher is fine.

Upgrade packages on one machine, then enable **offline_mode** on the server and upgrade the rest.